# Error "namespace mx.managers:ISystemManager not implemented by class " when converting application to flex sdk 4.6 from sdk 3.3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, adobe

I am converting my application to flex sdk 4.6 previously it was in sdk 3.3 and getting below errors.

```
1044: Interface method activate in namespace mx.managers:ISystemManager not implemented by class 

1044: Interface method addChildBridge in namespace mx.managers:ISystemManager not implemented by class
```

And some more errors, I am searching from hours but not get any solution.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?  Sometimes weird errors like this show up because of a version mismatch between a SWC library and the main SDK.

Comment: Hello Reboog711, thanks for your reply, Yes I cleaned the project many times. But not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a custom window (like the titlewindow).  **Are you?**  From reading the doc on ISystemManager, it  looks like your custom "window" class may need to implement iSystemManager.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/ISystemManager.html

Comment: Hi keithlee, Thanks for your reply. There are many titlewindows in application. It is working fine with 3.3 or 3.6 flex SDK, but I am getting these error only with flex SDK 4.6

Comment: Sorry for these long delay, I am still getting these errors. So I am still working with old SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My response is obviously too late. Besides who cares about adobe flex now. Anyway, just for justice's sake. Usually such errors appear when you're mixing different sdks in one project. I suppose that you have libs/projects compiled with SDK 3.x linked to your 4.6 project (in my case it was Cairngorm). The solution is to recompile linked projects with current SDK 4.x.